# Swap between two variables by reference in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I need to make a function that swaps two variables by reference (Transferring the values
should be on stack, not through registers), when i try to check if the values swapped I have  an error (on emu8086):
(11) wrong parameters: CMP  [ax], [bx]
(11) probably it's an undefined var: [ax]

```
org 100h 
include print.inc   ;printing library
start:
    x db 0x7Fh
    y db 0x80h
    lea ax, x   ;get address
    lea bx, y   ;get address 
    push ax
    push bx
    call swap
    cmp [ax], [bx]
    jl label1;check if values swapped
    jmp end2

label1:
    PRINTN "values swapped"   ;print if the values swapped
end2:
mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret


proc swap   ;swap function
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov cx, [bp + 4]
    xchg cx, [bp + 6]
    mov [bp + 4], cx  
    jmp end1

end1:
    pop bp
    ret
endp swap
```

Comment: `cmp` does not take two memory operands and even if it did, `[ax]` is not valid. Consult an instruction set reference.

Comment: Also better not put your `x` and `y` into the execution path.

Comment: Your `swap` is wrong as well, it does not dereference either pointer argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to implement the classic C swap:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{ 
int temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}
```

So I'll break down what needs to be done step-by-step. Firstly, you have your data defined after your `start` label and then code right after. Unless there's additional hardware abstraction going on here, the CPU will interpret the `0x7F` and `0x80` as CPU instructions, doing who knows what. So move your declared data to a different section.

```
proc swap   ;swap function
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
;sp + 0 = bp
;sp + 2 = ret
;sp + 4 = pushed bx
;sp + 6 = pushed ax
```

I like to have comments like these to remind myself which variable is which, since things get confusing very quickly.

Now, you have to remember that since you used `LEA` to populate `ax` and `bx`, what you have in those registers are pointers to memory. So `ax` does not equal `0x007F`, but rather *the address where that `0x007F` is stored.* So you'll need to dereference the arguments after loading them off the stack.

```
proc swap   ;swap function
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
;sp + 0 = bp
;sp + 2 = ret
;sp + 4 = pushed bx
;sp + 6 = pushed ax
    mov di,[bp + 4] ;loads &y into di
    mov si,[bp + 6] ;loads &x into si
    mov ax,[di]     ;loads 0x0080 into ax
    mov cx,[si]     ;loads 0x007F into cx

;now swap the values at those addresses

    mov [si],ax     ;*a = 0x0080
    mov [di],cx     ;*b = 0x007F
    pop bp
    ret
endp swap
```

Comment: In 16 bit mode you can not address relative to `sp`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I meant `bp`

Comment: I use NASM's macros to automatically create temporary defines for stack frames like this. Described briefly [in the ACEGALS](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/acegals.htm#stack-var-par) and [in the macro collection's comments](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/36a652946a11/lmacros2.mac#l25).